# Notepadqq is broken and reinstall doesn't help

Tags: notepadqq

There's several things wrong with my Notepadqq installation and I want to do a clean reinstall. How?

I already tried:

```
sudo apt purge notepadqq
sudo apt-get install notepadqq
```

Somehow I still ended up with the same broken installation.

I attached a screenshot of current Notepadqq state below. It shows menu bars and toolbars missing (unable to get them back with ALT+T). It also shows how the first letter of every row is partially hidden behind the column that shows row numbers.

[image]

Comment: Can you check in your ~/.config directory to see if there is a configuration folder or file for notepadqq?  If there is, you could try renaming or deleting it (while notepadqq is not running) and then restarting notepadqq

Comment: This worked. Thanks! If you want to post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program often store configurations in your local ~/.config file, which are not deleted even though the program itself is purged.

As a test, while `notepadqq` is not running, you can either rename or delete the configuration file for `notepadqq` and then restart the program, which will cause it to return to a default configuration.

In a terminal window:

```
cd ~/.config
mv <filename> <filename>.bak
exit
```

where `<filename>` is the name of the file or directory containing the configuration files for `notepadqq`